# How to Update data grid in C#,while updating new entries given will be insert at the same time?

Tags: c#

for updation i am used procedure ,but using below code i can only update existing ones

```
pt.PackageTariff_Update(var, dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),   
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(), 
int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is `pt` and `PackageTariff_Update` ?

Comment: PackageTariff_Update is one of my procedure for updation.and i am created a class library for my project PackageTariff_Update is defined inside class library , which is called by using object pt.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer ..i don't know if it is a correct method or not ..
code is given...

```
enter code here
         pt = new packagetariff();
         int var = int.Parse(combo_packTariffID.Text);
           for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
          {
            try
            {
                pt = new packagetariff();
                int Id = int.Parse(combo_packTariffID.Text.ToString());
                DataTable dt = pt.PackageTariff_View(Id);
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    a = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch { }

            if (a == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
                {

                 pt.PackageTariff_Update(var, dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(), int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()));

               }
        }

                if (a != dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    int Id = int.Parse(combo_packTariffID.Text.ToString());
                    pt = new packagetariff();
                    pt.delete_For_Update_tariff(Id);
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                    //pt.PackageTariff_Update(var, dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(), int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
                    pt.PackageTariff_Add(combo_packTariffID.Text,dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(),dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(),dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
```